# Delphi App Tethering with WiFi Direct?

Tags: android, delphi, wifi-direct, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm using Embarcadero RAD Studio 10.1 Berlin.

FireMonkey app tethering components are designed for traditional WiFi and Bluetooth coupling. Does it support also WiFi Direct connections?

I tried to use an Embarcadero Tethering example (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Berlin/en/RTL.MediaPlayer_Sample ). I arranged the Direct connection of my devices using an app called SuperBeam. Then I ran the 'MediaPlayer' on my PC and 'MediaPlayerCommand' on my Android phone.

Unfortunately, when I try to look for available apps from the perspective of 'MediaPlayerCommand' I get no results. During the debugging process I've encountered two socket errors:

- 19 - 'no such device', when 'AllowedAdapters' properties of both
  present TTetheringManager objects were set to 'Network_V4'
- 101 - 'network is unreachable' when I changed mentioned properties to 'Network'

The WiFi Direct connection exists and works, because I can access 192.168.49.1:8080 from my PC to download files exposed by SuperBeam (which means that I'm able to download files from my phone to my PC). My phone is Sony Xperia E4 (E2105).

I would really like to know if such a maneuver is possible.

Comment: I also did not get this up and running, nor for bluetooth paired devices (at least ANdroid-Phone to Windows 10 PC). Within a class C network everything is jolly fine. As the docs state "only class c networks supported - perhaps Wifi direct uses other network classes and other mechanisms for broadcasting. In this case, it would be great if Emba would expand the functionality.